Convexity Property of a Divergence Measure with Constant Factor
I have a divergence measure (D) that satisfies the following property for any functions $f_1$, $f_2$, and $g$:
$$D(\lambda f_1 + (1 - \lambda) f_2 \| g) \leq \frac{c_2}{c_1} \left( \lambda D(f_1 \| g) + (1 - \lambda) D(f_2 \| g) \right)$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. Is there a specific term for this type of "convexity"?
